# Typescript recursive check condition

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hello I have object structure which looks exactly like this:

```
Category {
 id: number;
 nestedCategories: Category[];
}
```

Now I need to use recursion to check if an category with given ID exists in parent or any children Category, the method signature looks like this:

```
checkIfExists(cat: Category) {
    return this.categoryViewService
      .getRawCategories()
      .filter(notChildren(cat));
}

notChildren(cat: Category) {
    //?
}
```

I have problems here because of scopes in Javascript language, could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Method filter have argument as method callback. May be, you can try this:

From:

```
checkIfExists(cat: Category) {
    return this.categoryViewService
      .getRawCategories()
      .filter(notChildren(cat));
}

notChildren(cat: Category) {
    //?
}
```

To:

```
checkIfExists(cat: Category) {
    return this.categoryViewService
      .getRawCategories()
      .filter(notChildren);
}

notChildren(cat: Category) {
    //?
}
```

Comment: Well yeah it looks better but doesn't resolve my problem, I dont know how to check if value exists in mutliple nested array

Comment: Simple recursive filter calls will do.

Comment: It's not working for me, doesn't filter all childrens